# How Do I calculate the difference of 2 time zones in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

For example, the difference in Eastern and Central is 1. My solution below feels hacky. Is there a easier / better way?

```
var diff = (parseInt(moment().tz("America/New_York").format("ZZ")) - parseInt(moment().tz("America/Chicago").format("ZZ"))) / 100;
```

My example is using the [Momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) library.

Comment: What about subtracting the [offsets](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/offset/)?

Comment: so something like `(moment().tz("America/New_York").zone() - moment().zone()) / 60` ? I guess that's a little better.

Comment: What exactly do you plan to do with it? Do you really need to use timezone by name?

Comment: In this case we do. The web server is in the Eastern time zone; we're in Central. I need the difference in the user's timezone and the server.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's impossible to calculate **the** difference between two arbitrary time zones.  You can only calculate a difference *for a specific moment in time*.

- It's *currently* 4 hours difference between London and New York (writing this on Mar 25, 2015).
- But it was 5 hours difference a few weeks ago, and it will be 5 a few weeks from now.
- Each time zone switches offsets for daylight saving time at a different point in time.

This is true in the general case between two time zones.  However *some* time zones either switch exactly at the same time, or don't switch at all.

- There is *always* one hour between London and Paris, because they switch at the same moment in time.
- There are *always* 3 hours between Arizona and Hawaii, because neither have DST.

Keep in mind that in the United States, each time zone that uses DST actually switches at a different moment in time. They all switch at 2:00 AM in their *local* time, but not at the same *universal* moment in time.

- So between Chicago and New York, there is *usually* 1 hour apart
- But for two brief periods each year they are either 2 hours apart, or have the *same exact time.*

See also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Now with regard to moment-timezone, you said in comments:

> *The web server is in the Eastern time zone; we're in Central. I need the difference in the user's timezone and the server.*

The time zone of the web server is irrelevant.  You should be able to host from anywhere in the world without affecting your application.  If you can't, then you're doing it wrong.

You *can* get the **current** time difference between *your* time zone (US Central time) and the user's.  You don't even need to know the user's exact time zone for this, if the code is running in the browser:

```
var now = moment();
var localOffset = now.utcOffset();
now.tz("America/Chicago"); // your time zone, not necessarily the server's
var centralOffset = now.utcOffset();
var diffInMinutes = localOffset - centralOffset;
```

If instead the code was running on the server (in a node.js app), then you *would* need to know the user's time zone.  Just change the first line like this:

```
var now = moment.tz("America/New_York"); // their time zone
```

### Updated answer:

This can be done *without* Moment, in environments that support the ECMAScript Internationalization API and have fully implemented IANA time zone support.  This is most browsers these days.

```
function getTimeZoneOffset(date, timeZone) {

  // Abuse the Intl API to get a local ISO 8601 string for a given time zone.
  let iso = date.toLocaleString('en-CA', { timeZone, hour12: false }).replace(', ', 'T');
  
  // Include the milliseconds from the original timestamp
  iso += '.' + date.getMilliseconds().toString().padStart(3, '0');
  
  // Lie to the Date object constructor that it's a UTC time.
  const lie = new Date(iso + 'Z');

  // Return the difference in timestamps, as minutes
  // Positive values are West of GMT, opposite of ISO 8601
  // this matches the output of `Date.getTimeZoneOffset`
  return -(lie - date) / 60 / 1000;
}
```

Example usage:

```
getTimeZoneOffset(new Date(2020, 3, 13), 'America/New_York') //=> 240
getTimeZoneOffset(new Date(2020, 3, 13), 'Asia/Shanghai') //=> -480
```

If you want the difference between them, you can simply subtract the results.

### Node.js

The above function works in Node.js where the `full-icu` [internationalization](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html) support is installed (which is the default for Node 13 and newer).  If you have an older version with either `system-icu` or `small-icu`, you can use this modified function.  It will work in browsers and `full-icu` environments also, but is a bit larger.  (I have tested this on Node 8.17.0 on Linux, and Node 12.13.1 on Windows.)

```
function getTimeZoneOffset(date, timeZone) {

  // Abuse the Intl API to get a local ISO 8601 string for a given time zone.
  const options = {timeZone, calendar: 'iso8601', year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit', hour12: false};
  const dateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, options);
  const parts = dateTimeFormat.formatToParts(date);
  const map = new Map(parts.map(x => [x.type, x.value]));
  const year = map.get('year');
  const month = map.get('month');
  const day = map.get('day');
  const hour = `${map.get('hour') % 24}`.padStart(2, "0"); // Sometimes hour value comes as 24
  const minute = map.get('minute');
  const second = map.get('second');
  const ms = date.getMilliseconds().toString().padStart(3, '0');
  const iso = `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hour}:${minute}:${second}.${ms}`;

  // Lie to the Date object constructor that it's a UTC time.
  const lie = new Date(iso + 'Z');

  // Return the difference in timestamps, as minutes
  // Positive values are West of GMT, opposite of ISO 8601
  // this matches the output of `Date.getTimeZoneOffset`
  return -(lie - date) / 60 / 1000;
}
```

Note that either way, we *must* go through `Intl` to have the time zone applied properly.

Comment: Tried it with node.js and it's not working - this line doesn't work `const lie = new Date(iso + 'Z')` when it parses this  date string `4/15/2020T08:43:57.710Z` the result is `NaN`. But maybe my node is too old `v8.3.0`

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin - Thanks for pointing that out.  The problem is that Node.js pre v13 comes with `small-icu` by default, which doesn't have locale support - so you get a system-locale format instead (`en-CA` y-m-d format isn't honored).  I've expanded my answer to include an alternative way, using the `formatToParts` API.  That should work for you without updating Node.

Comment: @ErKKChopra - IE11 does support `toLocaleString`, but it doesn't support IANA time zones.  If you require both time zone support and support for IE11 and other older browsers, you'll need to use an older library that brings its own time zone data instead of relying on `Intl`.  For example, https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: Nice work!
One note: `const hour = map.get('hour');` sometimes returns "24", which makes an invalid iso string. It needs a `hour==="24" ? "00" : hour;` check put in somewhere to fix it. This is with Node v12+ BTW.
Also, it doesn't hurt to round the result. I got some annoying unit test fails because `-0 !== 0`.

Comment: Interesting.  Though, 24 means 0 of the *following* day, so there would be a bit more math to do somwhere.  Probably easiest to adjust the lie.  Alternatively, I wonder if there's an Intl setting to avoid such a result.  Perhaps it would work better to pass some specific locale rather than `undefined`.  (BTW, [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html) will solve this properly.)

Comment: I did not quite understand. This function gets the offset at the time `new Date(2020, 3, 13), 'America/New_York'` or `new Date(2020, 3, 13) + 240*60*1000, 'America/New_York'`?

Comment: It looks to me like the last example is described either incorrectly or unintuitively. It returns the difference between the passed time zone and UTC, not between the passed time zone the user's

Comment: I hit the same case as Trevedhek. So suggesting an edit to replace const hour = map.get('hour') with `const hour = `${map.get('hour') % 24}`.padStart(2, "0")` @MattJohnson-Pint

Answer (score 1):

The difference between two timezones can only be measured w.r.t particular time because of things like Daylight saving time ([dst](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/)).

But, for a particular date, below code should work.

```
function getOffsetBetweenTimezonesForDate(date, timezone1, timezone2) {
  const timezone1Date = convertDateToAnotherTimeZone(date, timezone1);
  const timezone2Date = convertDateToAnotherTimeZone(date, timezone2);
  return timezone1Date.getTime() - timezone2Date.getTime();
}

function convertDateToAnotherTimeZone(date, timezone) {
  const dateString = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: timezone
  });
  return new Date(dateString);
}
```

The offset/difference is in milli sec

Then all you have to do is:

```
const offset = getOffsetBetweenTimezonesForDate(date, 'America/New_York', 'America/Chicago');
```

Comment: please look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29268535/2381172 - your answer does not provide any new information.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working Typescript code based on the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/a/29268535/7412781

```js
export function getTimeZoneOffset(date: Date, timeZone: string) {
  // Abuse the Intl API to get a local ISO 8601 string for a given time zone.
  const isoStrRaw: string = date
    .toLocaleString("en-CA", { timeZone, hour12: false })
    .replace(", ", "T");

  const toks: string[] = isoStrRaw.split("T");
  if (toks.length < 2) {
    throw Error(
      "getTimeZoneOffset: isoStrRaw(" +
        isoStrRaw +
        ") split with T failed. result toks(" +
        String(toks) +
        ")"
    );
  }

  // On some systems toLocalString() is ISO format YYYY-MM-DD, on some other systems, it's MM/DD/YYYY.
  let dateStr: string = toks[0];
  const toksD: string[] = dateStr.split("/");
  if (toksD.length == 3) {
    // This means dateStr is in MM/DD/YYYY format convert to ISO.
    dateStr =
      toksD[2] +
      "-" +
      toksD[0].padStart(2, "0") +
      "-" +
      toksD[1].padStart(2, "0");
  }
  const iso =
    dateStr +
    "T" +
    toks[1] +
    "." +
    date.getMilliseconds().toString().padStart(3, "0");

  // Lie to the Date object constructor that it's a UTC time.
  const lie = new Date(iso + "Z");
  if (lie == undefined) {
    throw Error(
      "getTimeZoneOffset: result lie is undefined. Check input string(" +
        iso +
        "Z)"
    );
  }

  // Return the difference in timestamps, as minutes
  // Positive values are West of GMT, opposite of ISO 8601
  // this matches the output of `Date.getTimeZoneOffset`
  return -(lie.getTime() - date.getTime()) / 60 / 1000;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

An easy way using toLocalString to get the difference with GMT of the timezones. Then you only need to substract.

```
var d = new Date();
    
var a = d.toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: 'Asia/Tokyo', timeZoneName: "short" }).split(/GMT/g)[1];
var b = d.toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: 'America/Montreal', timeZoneName: "short"  }).split(/GMT/g)[1];
var diff = a - b;
```