# Get Users Time and Subtract by Local Time

Tags: javascript, html, time

I am trying to get the users local time and subtract it with my own to get the time difference as an output.

This is what I have so far:

```js
var myTimezone = new Date();
var usersTimezone = 0; // UsersTimezone is missing
var timeDifference = myTimezone.getHours() - usersTimezone + " hours";

document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Time Difference: " + timeDifference;
```

```html
<div id="time">

</div>
```

I couldn't find a good solution to get the exact local time of the user, so maybe someone could help me here.

Thank you very much!

Comment: How would the user know about your time zone? When you create a new `Date` its created at the user, so you would need to ask the server for its `Date` using `ajax` or setting it when rendering the page

Comment: Since it's javascript, it will be the user's timezone, you could retain yours by a server side language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Easy way: without daylight saving time

Like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638018/current-time-formatting-with-javascript) there is a function `getTimezoneOffset()` to get the timezone of the user.

But you have to know in witch timezone you are, in my example you are in the timezone UTC+0.

```js
var myTimezone = 1;
var usersTimezone =  (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
var timeDifference = Math.abs(myTimezone + usersTimezone) + " hours";

document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Time Difference: " + timeDifference;
```

```html
<div id="time">

</div>
```

## Calculation with daylight saving time

The code below also looks at he [daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).
This is more complex and i used the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) for this.

Take also a look at this post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29268535/2801860

```js
var now = moment();
var usersOffset = now.utcOffset();
now.tz("Europe/Berlin"); // your time zone, not necessarily the server's
var myOffset = now.utcOffset();
var diffInMinutes = Math.abs(usersOffset - myOffset);
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Time Difference: " + (diffInMinutes/60);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>

<div id="time">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this totally makes sense for me. I'm located in Germany so UTC would be +1

Comment: do I need to have -1 as my timezone var ? Because +1 shows me a time difference of 2 hours.

Comment: sorry, the calculation was wrong, now it works - Germany is UTC+1

Comment: NICE! Thanks for this.. .What causes the problem with the calculation before?

Comment: Hi fab. thanks again. I just noticed one thing, today the time changed from winter into summertime and the time difference went from 0h to 1h. Is there a way to fix this? :)

Comment: @Dennis I updated the post with a example that also take care at the daylight saving time (sommertime, ..)

Comment: NICE ! Thanks for this!