# How to get UTC time difference for a given country?

Tags: javascript, time, timezone

I'm trying to get GMT time difference for the given country.

But I get wrong results, code produces `8` hours for Sydney instead of the correct `10`.

How it could be fixed?

```
const country = "Australia/Sydney"
const utc_ms = Date.now()
const local_s = new Date(utc_ms).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: country})
const local_ms = (new Date(local_s)).getTime()
const diff = (local_ms - utc_ms)/1000/60/60 // => 8 hours
```

**UPDATE**

Seems like the problem was that the local offset is missing, below seems to be the correct code. If you know shorter version please share your answer.

```
const country = "Australia/Sydney"

function timezone_offset_min(country: string) {
  const local_d = new Date()
  const remote_str = local_d.toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: country })
  const local_ms = local_d.getTime()
  const remote_ms = (new Date(remote_str)).getTime()
  const local_remote_offset = Math.round((local_ms - remote_ms) / (60 * 1000))
  const local_offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
  return local_remote_offset + local_offset
}

console.log(timezone_offset_min(country))
```

Comment: Please see the duplicate linked.  I added a solution to my answer there that doesn't require Moment.  It's similar to your approach, but more robust.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use moment.js. For detailed explanation, answer of this question is already posted [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265389/how-do-i-calculate-the-difference-of-2-time-zones-in-javascript).
Hope this post will help in solving this problem.

Comment: Thanks, seems like I missed my local time offset, I updated the code, it works ok now :)

Comment: Cool. Glad to hear that :-)

Comment: Hi.  Link-only answers are discouraged.  I agree that the post you linked is useful, but in the future please vote to close as duplicate, or reference the post in comments of the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure @MattJohnson-Pint. I will keep this in mind. Thanks for the heads up.